# VBA Word Create class module object from normal.dotm

Tags: vba, class, object, ms-word

I set up my own library with functions and subs for VBA (Word) and wanted to create a new class module. But I can't figure out how to use this new class with other files.

StopWatch Example (Normal.dotm, Class module: Global_StopWatch)

```vb
Private mlngStart As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub StartTimer()
    mlngStart = GetTickCount
End Sub
Public Function EndTimer() As Long    
    EndTimer = (GetTickCount - mlngStart)
End Function
```

StopWatch call (Document.dotm, module: Test)

```vb
Sub swTest()
    Dim gSW As Global_StopWatch
    Set gSW = New Global_StopWatch
        
    gSW.StartTimer
    Debug.Print "That took " & gSW.EndTimer & " ms."
End Sub
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/set-up-vb-project-using-class

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you, but the tutorial didn't work: `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined`. I tried both, early and late binding.

Comment: When describing an error it’s useful to mention which line is the problem...

Comment: I copy-pasted the complete code from your link to test if it's working. I get an `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined` on `Dim anEmployee As ClassProvider.clsEmployee` (`UseExportedClass_EarlyBinding()`). With `UseExportedClass_LateBinding()` I get a `Runtime Error: -2147352573 (800200003)`. Restarting Word doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry I guess that link is more Excel- focused.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal.dotm - clsStopWatch (Instancing = PublicNotCreatable)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private mlngStart As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub StartTimer()
    mlngStart = GetTickCount
End Sub
Public Function EndTimer() As Long
    EndTimer = (GetTickCount - mlngStart)
End Function
```

Normal.dotm - Module1

```vb
Public Function StopWatch() As clsStopWatch
    Set StopWatch = New clsStopWatch
End Function
```

Document1 - Module1

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim sw As normal.clsStopWatch, i As Long
    Set sw = normal.stopwatch
    sw.StartTimer
    For i = 1 To 10000000#
        '
    Next i
    Debug.Print sw.endtimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really do hate VBA sometimes..

Comment: I find Word VBA particularly challenging.  Excel VBA FTW!